# Which Lodash method is the most performant for object cloning?

Tags: javascript, object, lodash

Which method in Lodash preferred for object cloning in point of performance:

`var clone = _.cloneDeep(object)`

or

`var clone = _.merge({}, object)`

or

`var clone = _.assign({}, object)`

or somthing else? And why?

Comment: Not sure, but as per docs, `cloneDeep` is similar to `clone` and `clone` can be used over `DOM elements`, `date Objects` etc as well. So for performance, `merge` would be faster as it works only for `Array|Objects`

Comment: Also, merge can be used over multiple objects where as cloneDeep will copy objects/*, so I guess ideal way must be using `cloneDeep` instead of merge

Comment: @Rajesh that's answer material!

Comment: @EmileBergeron thanks. But i have hardly worked on lodash and so my comments are based on assumptions and understanding of JS. Would post one of i have credible facts to share.